# Problemas nos links usando ngRoute do Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

estou tentando criar links.
Estou trabalhando com AngularJS e fiz a parte de configuração de rotas.
Tenho uma pasta 'views' com os arquivos html.

Segue os códigos:

```
<html ng-app="fluxo">
<head>
<title>Fluxojoin</title>
<meta charset="utf8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fj.css">

<script>
angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);
angular.module("fluxo").controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

angular.module("fluxo").config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/entradas", {
        templateUrl: "views/entradas.html"
    });
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="fluxoCtrl">
<div ng-include="'views/links.html'"></div>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Arquivo entradas.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fj.css">

<div class="jumbotron" align="center">
<form name="contaEntradasForm">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="" placeholder="Nome">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="" placeholder="Email">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="" placeholder="Senha">
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta tirar a configuração do Router de dentro do controle. Se a ideia era passar a controller pra página que você ta renderizando, então faz desse jeito aqui abaixo, passando a controller na propria config:

```js
angular.module("fluxo", ["ngRoute"]);

angular.module("fluxo").config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/entradas", {
        templateUrl: "views/entradas.html",
        controller: 'fluxoCtrl'
    });
});
  
angular.module("fluxo").controller("fluxoCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

});
```

Comment: Isso mesmo @EduardoMartins! Deu certo.
Tenho que colocar a parte das rotas, antes e fora da parte do controller.
Valeu.